# Salescloud and Lead Conversion

Tags: lead-conversion, sales-cloud

I need assistance with a certain process I need to automate around Sales Cloud and Lead conversion.

Our current implementation automates the creation (and synchronization) of a Quote right after an Opportunity is created (via Process Builder and triggers).

The Contact field (which is required in the Quote) comes from a mandatory custom lookup field (Contact__c) in the Opportunity object.

We have been unable to do this upon Lead conversion!

Since the conversion creates an Account, a Contact and an Opportunity, we need to get the created Contact and fill it in the Contact__c in the Opportunity (so that the Quote can be created).

We know that this can be built using:

a) Process in the Process Builder (triggered when the new Contact -coming from a conversion- is created)
b) Flow (triggered to assign the ContactId value)
c) and back to the Process (it creates the Opportunity by assigning Contact__c = (flow).ContactId).

Can you please help me building this? I'm not an expert with Flows even when I know Process Builder.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much easier than you are considering and can be accomplished using only Process Builder.

Just create a PB on Lead with Converted = true criteria and mark the advanced check for "only when specified changes are made". Then you add a modify action on your Converted Opportunity Id, and set the opp's Contact to Converted Contact Id. Voila!

[image]

Comment: Thanks friend! It worked.